# getextra() putextra() having following error

Tags: android

```
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mani/com.example.mani.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at com.example.mani.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:25)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-02 14:51:23.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1524):     ... 11 more
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mani/com.example.mani.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.example.mani.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:26)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-02 14:55:46.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your logcat clearly shows that you have a NullPointerException on line 25 of `MapActivity`. The second crash shows one on line 26.

Comment: Please, show your code

Comment: There's about 5 minutes between the exceptions so likely you edited the code in the meanwhile. The latter trace is what's more relevant.

Comment: please include your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getExtras()` method returns a `Bundle` containing all the extras passed through the `Intent` but if there is no data passed, it returns `null`. Probably this is the root of your problem?

Comment: recovered. thnx a lot